# Plausible solution (apparently reasonable "definition") to space travel constraints

Tags: vacuum, faster-than-light, rocket-science, space-travel, warp-drives

Let me grab your attention for a moment for my physics questions.

Looking at the Alcubierre drive theory example.

There's a great example that works similar in terms of structure that works here on earth (a surfboard riding a wave).

If we were to find a similar constant like a wave, with the downward slope force in the back from a higher position,
With a simultaneous upward force for underneath the front tip which dips below the medium,
Could this create a net positive forward force?

Could this be achieved in the vacuum of space just like surfing here on earth? Could this create something similar to an Alcubierre drive without bending space time but utilizing already factual forces?

Could this work by utilizing leverage by leveraging force direction with equal but opposite force using a forward down and a forward up?

doing it with the use of fuel could be feasible?

since ya know there's minimal gravity in space and it only requires equal parts of force diagonally one down to the right and one up and to the right.
Theoretically the up and down force should cancel each other out since its a equal but opposite force leaving you with a net positive forward force of 2?

Id love to know your thoughts on this.

(Edited so hopefully my questions are not closed again)

(Please provide feedback
if closed again as to what i can do better so i can receive peer review for my questions)

My hopes are there are bright minds here that can breakdown these thought experiments that are open-minded within the guidelines of factual science.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty in finding a gentle explanation of why I voted to close. You said, "...thought experiments..." I don't see any thought experiment here. You asked me to imagine somebody riding a wave. OK. I don't even have to imagine that. I've done it. So, then what? What should I conclude? Should I conclude that _if_ there was a wave, I could ride it? Well how about this: If I dug a hole, and I found a box of gold coins, I could spend the money. But that doesn't tell me where I should dig. It doesn't even tell me _\*if\*_ there is a treasure waiting to be found anywhere on Earth...

Comment: ...Merely imagining that there is some kind of previously undiscovered wave phenomenon out in the vacuum of space, and imagining that I could discover some way to ride it does not tell me where or how I should look for it. It does not even tell me _\*if\*_ the phenomenon is out there waiting to be found.